# Threads in Android

Tags: android

I want to display data in my android application from the database in a gap of few seconds and update the UI using threads. So how can i separate the logic for both getting the data from the database and UI?

Comment: I'm not sure of your requirements.  Are you saying the read from the database will take a few seconds so you want to perform the operation in a background task?  Or are you saying that you just want to introduce a delay before the database read is performed?

Comment: @dave c. , dear Kartik is i think saying about the Async Operation, i mean to say he wants to fetch data from database, while fetching data from the database along with he wants to update the UI with some received data, i hope this is right, kartik ?

Comment: @paresh :

you are absolutely correct. I want to update UI by fetching the data from the database frequently.

Comment: I want an example related to it.

Comment: @PM-PareshMayani : I have used AsyncTask as you told..can you please post your comment as answer. so that i can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i used AsyncTask for managing UI and Background Processing

Answer (score 1):

if you have to kill the Activity before the AsyncTask finish the job , you can recover the it in another Activity using :

1- class code:
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask {
....
}

2- instance the class :

```
        dtdodo = new DownloadImageTask( this, p , codacaovalue);
        dtdodo.execute("wwwkjhdijdh");
```

3- Kill the Activity (event like rotate the screen).

4- recoveryng the AsyncTask :

```
onCreate(){
        Object retained = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        if ( retained instanceof DownloadImageTask ) {
                dtdodo = (DownloadImageTask) retained;
                dtdodo.setActivity(this);
        } else {
                dtdodo = new DownloadImageTask(this , 1 , codacaovalue);
                dtdodo.execute();
        }
}
```

I found this in a blog of a anonymous guy, I am justing sharing.

Comment: If this is from another source, you should tell where you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Then use TimerThread.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Comment: Finally i used AsyncTask for managing UI and Background Processing